# How to create list with different elements and actions?

Tags: android, list, android-intent

I want to create list with different types of items. They should call different intents or do other things (display a map etc.) . It should act like contact details. Numbers of items and actions is predefined.

[image: conact dteails]

How to achieve this effect elegantly? I don't need exact code but guidelines and information where to look. Any help will be appreciated :)

---

UPDATE:

By "this effect" I mean creating a list of different types of items (onClickListener, layout). On picture above you can see that you have a contact with various options: calling somebody, emailing, chatting, looking at google maps etc. All of those options are grouped at list.

I'm wondering if it could be achieved by xml layout without defining custom `Adapter` class. I want also be able to add some static header rows with eg. category name.

Comment: It is unclear what is the "this effect" that you are unclear upon.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain what I've meant by "this effect". Hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see to achieve this would be to indeed create a custom adapter class. 
I'm using this to create a file browsers, with different actions based on wether the item selected is a file or a folder.

Basically, You need to create a custom adapter extending ArrayAdapter (you can use another base class if all your items inherit from the same class). Here's a sample code :

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mList = objects;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Object obj = mList.get(position);
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyClass1.class)){
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myclass1_item_layout, null);
            setupViewClass1(obj,v);
        } else if (obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyClass2.class)){
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myclass2_item_layout, null);
            setupViewClass2(obj,v);
        }

        return v;
    }

    private void setupViewClass1 (Object obj, View v){  
        // setup the content of your view (labels, images, ...)
    }

    private void setupViewClass2 (Object obj, View v){  
        // setup the content of your view (labels, images, ...)
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> mList;

}
```

Then you need to add an OnItemClickListener as well as an OnCreateContextMenuListener to handle the click and longpress event on your list, again making a filter on the class of your object.