# Displaying different type of rows in an Android list

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of polymorphic entities, for example `List<Person>` where a person can be employee, manager, soldier, royalty, etc... and I want to display the person list in an android list-view where each type of person has different row template and somewhat different data.

**What is the proper way to display the different rows of different types?**

Two bad(?) solutions:

1. Put an abstract `getView` method inside the `Person` class, so that each different person will create the correct view via polymorphism. --> This will mix the model and the view of MVC - ie. if I will want to present the list in a different screen (for example a table view) then it will break.
2. Put the model-to-view logic inside the adapter (inherited from `ArrayAdapter<Person>`). For example inside `getView` I can check the `getClass()` of the person and fill the correct view accordingly. --> This method will end up with long chain of if-else statements, one for each person type, and will need to be extended when new types of persons are added - usually a smell of bad code in object oriented point of view.  This is the solution suggested in "[How to create list with different elements and actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825377/how-to-create-list-with-different-elements-and-actions)"

Is there a solution better than (2) above?

Comment: This is one of the most troublesome questions in all of Android UI design. I would love to see more android experts weighing in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally go for something similar to your second solution. I'd probably include an abstract method in the `Person` class to identify the type of person, so you can use that instead of checking with `getClass()` on the `Person` object in the `getView()` call.

In your custom adapter, extend `BaseAdapter` and be sure that `getViewTypeCount()` returns the number of different kinds of persons you have in your data set and that `getItemViewType(int position)` returns the correct identifier for the position in your data set.

This question has a lot of useful information on the subject:

[getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter)

Comment: Ok so 3 answers suggesting the same solution - I guess there is no better way.  I'm choosing your answer mostly for being the quickest, and also for pointing me to the getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType explanation.

Comment: It actually isn't a bad way to do it. Like I said, you can create an abstract method in your Person class, and that can be used in the getItemViewType() method as well. Also, check out the ViewHolder pattern - that can improve your performance even further.

Comment: It isn't a terrible solution, but it is bad. Adding/removing types requires changing 3 functions, and having `getItemViewType` out of sync with `getView` will be discovered in runtime and not compile time.  I imagine a solution where adding support for a new type of row would be just throwing a new class into the project, and maybe adding a line of code to wire it up to the adapter.

Comment: Edit: you are right that adding an abstract method for getItemViewType will remove the risk of out-of-sync with getView and will remove the necessity to  edit that function for new types, so the downsides I listed are somewhat muted.

Answer (score 1):

create your own ListAdapter which extends from BaseAdapter like this

```
public class YourListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
...
}
```

override the getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType()

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;//count of types
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return YourPersonList.get(position).getMyViewType();
}
```

and in the getView(..)

```
int type = getItemViewType(position);
switch(type){
case 0:
 //set the view to your layout
break;
case 1:
 //set the view to another layout
break;
}
```

more or less something like that..

//EDIT: look at the post from michell  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17152430/1847899

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you can override in an adapter that make this easier. They are:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount(){
  return viewTypeCount;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos){
  if (getItem(pos).type == employee)
    return VIEW_TYPE_EMPLOYEE;
  else if (getItem(pos).type == manager)
    return VIEW_TYPE_MANAGER;
}
```

Using the above methods, you still need to do some work, for instance when the view needs to be inflated you may have to call getItemViewType(position) from inside getView, but when you get a view that has been recycled, the adapter should give you the proper type based on the row position.